# C# hierarchy of dictionaries to xml string?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xml-serialization

Please show me how to serialize object of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>`. This object do not contain custom structs, but it can (not must) contain another objects (values) of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>`. As for simple it is hierarchy of dictionaries or some other generic types. I can write my own walking while serializing, but maybe you'll show me shortest way;)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this manually. I wouldn't trust the XML Serializer to make sense of anything like this.

Use LINQ to XML - it's the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

you could try using XmlSerializer provided your "object" is serializable

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> data = LoadData(); // however you populate your collection
var dataAsList = data.ToList(); 
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataAsList.GetType());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(sw,dataAsList );
var xml = sw.ToString();
...
...
```